# How can I make sure my tests start and run correctly?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, producer-consumer, dataflow

I'm determining between using TPL Dataflow blocks or some sort of  producer/consumer approach for these tests. Producing a list of tasks will be super-fast, as each task will just be a string containing a list of test parameters such as the setup parameters, the measurements required, and time between measurements. This list of tasks will simply be files loaded through the GUI (1 file per test).

When at test is started, it should start right away. The tests could be very long and very asynchronous in that an action could take seconds or tens of minutes  (e.g. heating up a device), followed by a measurement that takes a few seconds (or minutes), followed by a long period of inaction (24 hours) before the test is repeated again.

I could have up to 16 tests running at the same time, but I need the flexibility to be able to cancel any one of those tests at any time. I also need to be able to ADD a new test at any time (i.e. try to picture testing of 16 devices, or the span of a month in which individual test devices are added and removed throughout the month).

(Visual C#) I tried this example code for TPL dataflow where I tell it to run 32 simple tasks all at the same time. Each task is just a 5 second delay to simulate work. It appears to be processing the tasks in parallel as the time to complete the tasks took 15 seconds. I assume all 32 tasks did not finish in 5 seconds due to scheduling and any other overhead, but I am a bit worried that some task might of been blocked.

```
    class Program
    {
    // Performs several computations by using dataflow and returns the elapsed
    // time required to perform the computations.
    static TimeSpan TimeDataflowComputations(int messageCount)
    {
    // Create an ActionBlock<int> that performs some work.
    var workerBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(
        // Simulate work by suspending the current thread.

        millisecondsTimeout => Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout),
       // Specify a maximum degree of parallelism.
       new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
       {
           MaxDegreeOfParallelism = messageCount
       });


    // Compute the time that it takes for several messages to 
    // flow through the dataflow block.

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < messageCount; i++)
    {
        workerBlock.Post(5000);  // simulated work: a delay of 5 seconds.
    }
    workerBlock.Complete();

    // Wait for all messages to propagate through the network.
    workerBlock.Completion.Wait();

    // Stop the timer and return the elapsed number of milliseconds.
    stopwatch.Stop();
    return stopwatch.Elapsed;
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    int messageCount = 32; 

    TimeSpan elapsed;

    // set processors  maximum degree of parallelism. This causes
    // multiple messages to be processed in parallel.

    Console.WriteLine("START:\r\n");
    elapsed = TimeDataflowComputations(messageCount);
    Console.WriteLine("message count = {1}; " +
       "elapsed time = {2}ms.", messageCount, 
        (int)elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

    Console.ReadLine();
    } 
    }
```

The demo seems to work, but I am not sure if any of the tasks were blocked until one or more of the 5 second tasks were completed. I am also not sure how one would go about identifying each action block in order to cancel a specific one.

Comment: FWIW, `// Wait for all messages to propagate through the network.` can be true only true if `messageCount <= MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, though it appears there is something else going on (blocking?). Calling `workerBlock.Complete()` instructs the action block to stop accepting new work after it has completed its current work. Calling `Complete()` abandons any work not yet started. I do not understand the "15 seconds" part, that does seem to imply blocking. What happens if you add a counter to represent finished tasks?

Comment: Oh, you have only 1 block. You would often have more than one block, say a `BufferBlock` that serves as the queue. You would then `.LinkTo()` the action block, and feed the work to the `BufferBlock`. You might give that a try as well.

Comment: In order to add or cancel tests you will need a user interface that identifies when each test starts and stops. You will also need a command within your Main function allowing you to identify a new test to run or an existing test to cancel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you don't get the expected performance is because your workload is synchronous and blocks the thread-pool threads. Do you expect to actually have synchronous (blocking) workload in your production environment? If yes, you could try boosting the `ThreadPool` reserve of available threads before starting the TPL Dataflow pipeline:

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(workerThreads: 100, completionPortThreads: 100);
```

If your actual workload is asynchronous, then you could better simulate it with `Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`.

```
var workerBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(async millisecondsTimeout =>
{
    await Task.Delay(millisecondsTimeout);
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = messageCount
});
```

I didn't test it, but you should get completion times at around 5 sec with both these approaches.

Comment: The workload is asynchronous.  I tested both and they both work, and give the expected result.  Just my own FYI: I also found that the simulated (synchronous) work delay of 5 seconds was short enough to magnify the blocking of the threadpool threads by Thread.Sleep.  If the delay was set to simulate work taking 120 seconds then the total completion time of all 32 threads was 144 seconds.

Comment: @user2972161 yeap, the current `ThreadPool` implementation when starved from threads spawns one new thread every 500 msec. Configuring the `SetMinThreads` should be reserved for special/rare cases. Like for example if you are unlucky enough to be forced to use an API that initiates I/O operations by blocking one thread per operation. If your code (your own and the APIs you use) follow good async practices, thread pool starvation should never be an issue.